# can the degree sequence's sum be odd? or does it have to be even?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

for the problem below im getting odd, and I saw on a video that all degree sequence sum should add up to even..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about the sum of the degrees over all the vertices. This is always even.

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be the vertices of the graph, and let $\deg_{A_i}$ be the degree of the vertex $A_i$. We wish to prove that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \deg_{A_i} \equiv 0\mod 2$$

Note that this sum is really just a sum over edges. Consider the edge between vertices $A_i,A_j$. It is counted twice in the sum - once as part of $\deg_{A_i}$ and once as part of $\deg_{A_j}$. This is true for each edge, so this sum is

$$2E$$

where $E$ is the number of edges. This is even.

Comment: okay { 2 * (number of edges) } ; what if you have V = {A, B, C, D, E } & E = { ( A, B), (B, C) , (C, D), (D,E), (E,A)} after drawing it out i got 5 vertices, 5 edges, and a degree sequence of {2,2,2,2,2,2}. adding them up you get 12. though, in the drawing you have 5 edges, and 2 * 5 = 10... haha sorry if this is confusing its just im confused

Comment: There are only $5$ vertices, so you get a degree sequence of $\{2,2,2,2,2\}$. Also, I think the problem just has the edges being $(A,B),(B,C),(C,D),(D,E)$ with no $(E,A)$ edge, which shifts your answer a bit.